# Ionic 3 + Firestore recover value from a boolean field

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve the actual value of a boolean that is inside a document in Firestore.
**I have the following code:**

```
  isFollowing: boolean;
  following;

  ionViewDidLoad(){
  const userId = this.navParams.get('userId');
  const currentUserId = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;

  // checks if the currently logged in user is following the user
 this.following = this.followSvc.getFollowing(currentUserId, userId)

 .valueChanges().subscribe(following => {

  this.isFollowing = this.following

 })
 }
```

**I also have the following provider that selects the document to be read:**

```
getFollowing(currentUserId: string, userId: string) {
   return this.db.doc(`ProfileUser/${currentUserId}/following/${userId}`)
 }
```

**I have a ng-template of a follow button, which is changed as the boolean value, if it is clicked it creates the boolean key in the firestore with the id + TRUE and the button becomes Unfollow**

```
toggleFollow() {

const userId = this.navParams.get('userId');
const currentUserId = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;

if (this.isFollowing) this.followSvc.unfollow(currentUserId, userId)
else  return this.followSvc.follow(currentUserId, userId)
```

}

**below the field and the value that I need to recover**

[image]

**here is the problem when the user is being followed is ok .. because when it is not yet being followed it still returns TRUE and the button gets the wrong template**

[image]
[image]

**How to do this?**

Comment: I think you need to change the way where retrieve the data from firestore.Hope this helps to you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I also think I'm recovering the wrong way ... I'll read the article ... thanks for the help :)